# Entity Framework and SQL Server compact - database provider is incompatible

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I have Entity Framework 6.13 and I installed the `EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.6.1.3` NuGet package.

However, when I try to add a new model generated from the database I get error:

> Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework;
>   however, an Entity Framework database provider compatible with this
>   version could not be found for your data connection.  If you have
>   already installed a compatible provider, ensure you have rebuilt your
>   project before  performing this action. Otherwise, exit this wizard,
>   install a compatible provider, and rebuild  your project before
>   performing this action.

I have [SQL Server CE 4.3](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1) installed.

Part of `app.config` file:

```
<DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
    <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" 
         invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" 
         description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" 
         type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
</DbProviderFactories>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataBaseModelContainer" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataBaseModel.csdl|res://*/DataBaseModel.ssdl|res://*/DataBaseModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\MyProj-master\SignalRSelfHost\ClientLocationSignalHost.sdf&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />       
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Please show your connection string

Comment: Install the SQL Server Compact 4,0 runtime MSI, install the latest EF Tools for Visual Studio, connect to the database file from the Toolbox

Answer (score 1):

Install the SQL Server Compact 4,0 runtime MSI, install the latest EF Tools for Visual Studio, connect to the database file from the SQL Server Compact Toolbox